# How can i select an Edge loop when using a graphic tablet?

Tags: mesh, selection-tools

As the title says, Im using a graphic tablet with blender. Just wanted to try and use blender with it, but now I have a problem.

I have to check "emulate 3 button mouse" in User Preferences, so I can zoom, rotate and pan the view with the pencil using Alt, Alt+Ctrl and Alt+Shift.
The problem is that Edge loop shortcut is Alt + Left click, and that is the way I can rotate the view in the 3D view, so when I press Alt and the pencil, it rotates the view instead of selecting any edge loop.

I can select loops in the 3D view menu, Select > Edge loop but it´s really annoying to do that each time I need it, so a shortcut would be really better.

Do I have to create a new shortcut to Select Edge Loop? If so, what do you recommend? What should I do?
Thanks! :)

Comment: You can change the shortcut, that is always an option. If you have a stylus with multiple buttons (like wacom one), you can setup one button as middle-click, works fine.

Comment: Ooooh yeah, that works! I have a Huion 1060, but the stylus has 2 buttons, so i can disable "emulate 3 button mouse" and rotate pressing the button and hovering over the tablet, zoom pressing ctrl and the button in the stylus, or moving pressing Shift and the stylus button.
Thank you a lot, how can i vote your response? Im new here XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have to create a new shortcut to Select Edge Loop? If so, what do you recommend? What should I do?

Changing the shortcut is one possibility.

Another way is to map a middle-click to your stylus button (I use 2 button stylus with lower one set to middle and the other one to right click). This way the viewport navigation works with default shorcuts so there is no need to change other ones. Also left click (stylus tip) select works the best with a tablet (imho) - I did not encounter this non-default option colliding with any other shortcut or UI functionality.